# Naming Convention in Spring Beans

Tags: spring, javabeans

What is a property in a Spring Bean?

Does a getter method define a property.

For e.g. if there is a getPropertyName() method in a class, then will "name" automatically become a property? Or will a corresponding setter method be required? Or can a property be defined just by a variable name.

There are various examples,

In some:-
Spring POJO defines just a variable and it is used as a property of Spring bean. There are no getter or setter methods.

Whereas in some,
either just a setPropertyName or just a getPropertyName is used and it is called a property of Spring Bean

Spring Beans do not stringently follow Java Beans Specification, therefore I am asking this question.

Kindly reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring beans happen to have "bean" in their name, but they're not really related to Java beans.

A property of a Spring bean is the same as a property of any other Java object: something which is optionally readable through a getter and optionally writable through a setter. Whether the object is a spring bean or not doesn't change the definition.

Comment: @Nizet, What about the cases where just a variable name is used in a class without any getter or setter method. Will that variable be called a property?

Comment: No. It will be called a field, or an attribute.

Comment: @Nizet Respected Sir, I am studying Spring in Action 3rd Edition. There, they use the term property for even a variable. Is there a slightest chance that you may let me know why. Anyways, Thanks a ton for your answer, Sir

Comment: The reason is probably that they made a mistake, or abuse the term property.

Comment: Thanks Sir... Or Perhaps I misunderstood, I'll read the book again and would let you know

Answer (score 0):

Spring properties follows the common naming conventions in Java.

If you have this fields in a class:

```
String  title;
String  message;



Your get/set methods you'll be:


public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}
```

And in your properties you'll be using like:

```
<bean id="myclass" class="org.mypackage.myclass">
<property name="title" value="Big Title"></property>
<property name="message" value="Awesome Message"></property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, respected friend. My question is about those classes where there are neither setter methods nor getter methods. There just variable names are used as property and are set by "@Autowired" annotations.